# How to set the default unauthenticated path/model with multiple devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `rails` 5.2 application, using `devise` 4.4.3, which has two devise models: `User` and `Parent`.

The paths are defined the `config/routes.rb` as:

```
devise_for :users, path: 'users'
devise_for :parents, path: 'parents'
```

Currently when I visit an action that required authentication in an unauthenticated session I'm getting redirected to a `/parents/sign_in`, but I want to specify `/users/sign_in` as the default unauthenticated path.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've tried changing the order in the `routes.rb`, but that doesn't appear to have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `unauthenticated` call and define the default root route:

```
unauthenticated do
  root to: "users#sign_in"
end
```

Comment: Does this require creating a `UsersController`? I'm getting a `uninitialized constant UsersController` Routing Error. I've tried pointing to the devise controller action with `root to: 'devise/sessions#new'`, but that's giving an unknown action error from devise due to the lack of scope. I've tried with a scope: `as :user do root to: 'devise/sessions#new' end`, but that triggers an infinite redirect loop.